# Meaning of "for indeed"?

Tags: idioms, archaicisms

Given is the following paragraph (excerpt from The New Freedom, by Woodrow Wilson - 1913):

> **For indeed**, if you stop to think about it, nothing could
> be a greater departure from original Americanism, from
> faith in the ability of a confident, resourceful, and
> independent people, than the discouraging doctrine that
> somebody has got to provide prosperity for the rest of us.

What's the meaning of *for indeed* at the passage entry?

Comment: Try substituting “Truly,”

Comment: *For*, here, means "because". *Indeed*, here, means "indeed".

Comment: If it was written now, 'for' wouldn't be there. It is possible that it meant 'for sure', though it leads to redundancy in meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, how I see it, a combination of words used outside any commonplace English use. For situations like these, I going back to the basics and look at a dictionary definition of all the words, and attempt to draw a meaning.

(I am using Merriam Webster.)

Here is "for" that could apply:

> Used as a function word to indicate purpose.

> Used as a function word to indicate an intended goal.

> Used as a function word to indicate the object or recipient of a perception, desire, or activity. (It seems as if your quote is leaning toward this meaning.)

These meanings are connected with other expressions like "for certain," "for sure," "for [purpose]."

Here is "indeed" that could apply:

> All things considered[;] as a matter of fact.

When we read Woodrow's lines, we see that he is attempting to draw attention to some conclusion when one thinks "about it", which is a similar premise to "consider[ing]," as in the definition.

For extra consideration, I looked up other uses of "for indeed"; I found this Bible quote (the first) of Luke 1:66, and I also found this quote (the second) from the Quran (94:5):

> "For indeed, the hands of the lord was on him."

> "For indeed, with hardship [will be] ease."

The use of "indeed" here seems to differ in an interpretive meaning from Woodrow's quote, but the basic idea we can get is this:

> **For**: To identify the object/recipient of a view (here it is "indeed").

> **Indeed**: As a matter of fact; everything considered.

This can define the construction "for indeed" possibly as **"For a matter of fact,"** as "indeed" (used to show certainty) is connected to "for" (which identifies a purpose).

To connect this to your quote, Woodrow is saying that if one stops and thinks, they can realize some truth about the current situation; since "indeed" is commonly used to indicate some obvious truth, the addition of "for" adds a nuance of purpose/receiving action.

(I see I explained this in a very interpretive and convoluted way (I did not even consider the fact that "indeed" is an adverb), so by all means if someone is able to provide a more direct and concrete answer. I hope that this still can help you form some type of idea.)

EDIT: Jim's comment goes through a much more simpler reasoning: It is simply reinforcing the statement, like what "yea," "forsooth," or "indeed" alone would do.

Comment: That's a very nice and constructive answer, way to go @BigRigz!